# Counting Eisenstein primes

Tags: code-golf, primes, hexagonal-grid, complex-numbers

## Introduction

**Eisenstein integers** are complex numbers of the form

`a+bω`

Where `a,b` are integers, and

`ω = e^(2πi/3)`

The Eisenstein integers form a triangular lattice in the complex plane:

[image: Eisenstein Integers in the Complex Plane]

We say that an Eisenstein integer `z=a+bω` is **prime** if it cannot be written as the product of two non-unit (not 1,-1,ω,-ω,ω^2, or -ω^2) Eisenstein integers

## Program

**Input**: A natural number `n`.

**Output**: The number of Eisenstein primes which are of the form `a+bω` for which `a,b` are natural numbers (including zero) less than or equal to `n`

## Test Cases

0 → 0

1 → 0

2 → 5

3 → 9

4 → 13

5 → 20

## Scoring

This is `code-golf`, so least amount of bytes wins

Comment: Could you provide some test cases?

Comment: I don't understand the test cases. The number of `a,b` pairs for `2` is only `4` so how could `5` of them be prime?

Comment: @Maltysen let me rewrite the definition

Comment: @user3502615 i'm talking about the part where you say "are of the form a+bω for which a,b are natural numbers (including zero) less than n"

Comment: @Maltysen There are 5 numbers: 2ω, 2ω+1,2ω+2,ω+2, and 2

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading: the obvious interpretation would be [OEIS A003627](https://oeis.org/A003627).

Comment: @user3502615 you had less than, not equal to before. it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Jelly, 24 bytes

```
Rð_²+×µ€µ³RḊm3,µÆP×1¦3FS
```

Roughly the same approach as my Julia answer.

```
                          Initial argument: n
R                           Compute [1, 2, …, n]
 ð_²+×                      (λ, ρ) —→ (λ − ρ)² + λρ (which is λ² − λρ + ρ²)
      µ€                    Zip with itself. Call this Q.

        µ                 Refocus argument: Q
         ³                  The initial argument n
          RḊm3              Compute candidate green line primes: [2, 5, 8, …, n]
              ,             Call this P. Make pair with argument.

               µ          Refocus argument: [P, Q]
                ÆP          Check primality
                  ×1¦3      Multiply the first element by 3
                      FS    Sum everything
                            (The result is 3·countprimes(P) + countprimes(Q))
```

Answer (score 8):

## Julia, <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```
!n=sum(isprime,[a<1<b%3?b:a^2-a*b+b^2for a=[0;0;0:n],b=0:n])
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49c3VtKGlzcHJpbWUsW2E8MTxiJTM_YjphXjItYSpiK2JeMmZvciBhPVswOzA7MDpuXSxiPTA6bl0pCgpwcmludChtYXAoISwwOjUpKQ&input=)

### Explanation

We’re interested in the primes in this parallelogram on the complex plane (example for **n = 4**):

[image]

We can split them into primes on the **green lines**, and on the **gray lines**.

Wikipedia tells me an Eisenstein number **z** is a **green line Eisenstein prime** iff **|z|** is a natural prime equal to **2** mod 3.

It also says **z** is a **gray line Eisenstein prime** iff **|z|² = a² − ab + b²** is a natural prime.

---

So we loop over **a = 0…n** and **b = 0…n**, and check:

- If **(a = 0 or b = 0 or a = b)** and **max(a, b) % 3 = 2**, then count whether **max(a, b)** is a prime.
- Else, count whether **a² − ab + b²** is a prime.

However, we can abuse the distribution’s symmetry. Instead of counting each green line once, we can just count one green line thrice! That is, only check **a = 0** and increment the counter by three when we find a green line prime. The `a=[0;0;0:n]` achieves exactly this.

Since we know we’re only considering the green line **a = 0**, we can replace **max(a, b)** by **b**.

The “green line condition” is nicely expressed in Julia using operator chaining: `a<1<b%3`.

(For the remaining green lines, we will never return a false positive: if **a = b** or **b = 0** then **a² − ab + b² = a²**, which can’t be prime.)

### Ideas

Maybe, instead of writing `a^2-a*b+b^2`, I can conditionally replace the exponent at `b` by `1` when `a<1<b%3` – then the expression reduces to `b`. This doesn’t seem to be shorter, but it’s neat!

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (34 bytes)

```
qi,:)_2m*{_:*\:-_*+}%\1>3%3*+:mp1b
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qi%2C%3A)_2m*%7B_%3A*%5C%3A-_*%2B%7D%25%5C1%3E3%253*%2B%3Amp1b&input=5)